# Javafx creating players and pieces for chutes and ladders

Tags: java, javafx

I have an assignment where I am to create a chutes and ladder game using JavaFX.

What I am currently stuck on is once the user selects how many players they want, the method I run pushes an error.

I have run it through the debugger and I know what line is the problem, but I have no idea where to go from here.

The exception is:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

I found that if I change the zero in `private Players [] players = new Players[0];` to a 4, it works. However, I get another error if I try to change the 0 in `private Circle [] c = new Circle[0];`

```
public class Main extends Application {
private final int BOARD_DIM = 10;
private Players [] players = new Players[0];
private Circle [] c = new Circle[0];

public static void main(String[]args){
    launch();
}

public void start(Stage pStage) throws Exception{
    //ROOT PANE
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    //MENUBAR

    //BOARD CREATION

    //PLAYER SELECTION/RESUME PREVIOUS GAME
    //Drop down menu
    HBox players = new HBox();
    Label intro = new Label("Select # of players");
    ChoiceBox<String> p = new ChoiceBox<>();
    p.getItems().addAll("2","3","4");
    p.setPadding(new Insets(6));
    //Button to start new game
    Button startGame = new Button("Start Game");
    startGame.setOnAction(e -> getChoice(p));
    startGame.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    players.getChildren().addAll(intro,p,startGame);
    root.setRight(players);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 650);
    pStage.setTitle("Chutes and Ladders");
    pStage.setScene(scene);
    pStage.show();
}
private void getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> p) {
    int numOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(p.getValue());
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++){
        players[i] = new Players("p"+(i+1),9,0, false);
        c[i] = new Circle(25);
    }
    c[0].setFill(Color.GREEN);
    c[1].setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    if(numOfPlayers >= 3){
        c[2].setFill(Color.RED);
        }
        if(numOfPlayers == 4){
            c[3].setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error/exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are initalizing players and c as arrays with length 0. And in the loop you are iterating over the elements from 0 to numOfPlayers. That's what is causing the exception.

First just declare your arrays:

```
private Players [] players;
private Circle [] c;
```

Then in the your method, initalize the arrays with the length you need (If you need to alter the length later I would suggest to switch to ArrayLists).

```
private void getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> p) {
    int numOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(p.getValue());
    c = new Circle[numOfPlayers];            //add these lines
    players = new Players[numOfPlayers];     //add these lines
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++){
        players[i] = new Players("p"+(i+1),9,0, false);
        c[i] = new Circle(25);
    }
    ...
}
```